# Prove an ideal $I$ defines a finite set of points

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, ideals, projective-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

Let me start with some background: I am studying defining ideal of finite sets of points and have recently noticed the importance of the Hilbert function and polynomial in investigating this problem.
However, being new to these concepts, I have encountered certain problems that I hope you could help with.

My main interest is in determining (or rather proving) that a ideal $I$ is in fact the defining ideal of a finite set of points (and also know the cardinality of this set of points).
As an easy example, let us look at the ideal $(x_2^2-x_1^2,x_3^2-x_1^2) \subset T:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. I want to show $I$ is the ideal of $4$ points, and I read the Hilbert polynomial of $\frac{T}{I}$ plays a crucial role here.
I clearly see that the Hilbert polynomial of $\frac{T}{I}$ is the constant $4$. I suppose the conclusion now follows from the following two claims

- The degree of the Hilbert polynomial of $\frac{T}{I}$ equals the dimension of $V(I)$. 
  However I failed to find a clear proof of this fact, which would at least give an algorithm to show whether or not an ideal defines a finite set of points.
  Just compute the Hilbert polynomial of $\frac{T}{I}$ (which I can do with Macauley2 in hard cases) and check if the degree is $0$.
  Can someone point me in the right direction of a proof for this fact or recommend a source?
- Suppose $I$ defines a finite set of points $X$. Then we already know that its Hilbert polynomial is a constant. But now even stronger, this constant is $|X|$.
  Can someone again lead me in the right direction to prove this statement? (Assuming it is correct)

Is my reasoning above correct?

Any help regarding this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Proof of the first fact - degree of Hilbert polynomial is same as dimension of underlying variety - follows (e.g.) by Hartshorne's Chapter I, section 7, Theorem 7.5. For the second fact - your algebraic set has dimension 0 (by first fact) and degree of a point is 1.  Now look at proposition 7.6 (b) (op. cit).